# Why do some electronics drain the battery when the batteries are loaded while other electronics do not?

Tags: batteries

Common household electronics such as the multimeter, flashlight, or weight scale require batteries, but I noticed some will drain batteries loaded in them without having to turn them on, while other electronics will not drain the batteries.

It's very frustrating when one needed to use, say a flashlight, then found out the batteries loaded in there have been drained.

Is there a way to differentiate these electronics? (For example, a logo on a product that shows the product doesn't drain the battery when loaded.)

Comment: never found a flashlight that drains batteries when it is OFF... But if you leave discharged batteries in it they then fail...

Comment: An open mechanical switch does not leak nearly as much current as a transistor that is not conducting. Flashlights shouldn't leak though.

Comment: Generally it's best to not leave batteries in things that aren't being used.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices have a hard mechanical on/off switch that breaks the connection between the batteries and device. These shouldn't drain the batteries at all.

Some have electronic power switches. These will draw varying small amounts of current depending on how they are implemented. A device may for example have a circuit to detect the on/off press that needs to use some current to power it. There may be a microprocessor that is kept running in a low power state waiting for some input to cause it to power up fully, such as a scale that senses someone stepping on it.

The amount of current drawn by these is still going to be very low. More likely what you're seeing with batteries being dead when you go to use them after a period of storage is the self-discharge of the batteries. Different battery chemistries will have different self-discharge rates, some lasting for years when there's no load on them, some discharging rather quickly, with rechargeable types tending to self-discharge faster than non-rechargeable types. See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-discharge).

Comment: Some very old batteries have quite close to zero self-discharge, but modern ones won't--the extremely low self-discharge was achieved with the help of mercury metal, which is very illegal to use in batteries nowadays for obvious reasons.